# Cypress test runner does not appear and also some more options appear

Tags: cypress, cucumberjs, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have been trying to run my first cypress project. It worked until yesterday and now it keeps showing me this  when I select the Electron browser (I can't run script with other browsers as they keep stopping itself)

[image: Before selecting Electron]
[image: After selecting Electron]

Comment: Is there any output in the terminal where you ran your `cypress open` command?

Comment: @agoff, There was nothing unusual in the terminal.